# Symmetric Brick Stacking

Tags: combinatorics, symmetry

Suppose you stack $n$ LEGO bricks ($2 \times 1$) in a plane, where

- The base is contiguous
- Each level is offset from the level below it by one stud.
- Bricks are only stacked on top of other bricks, not below.

It turns out that there are exactly $3^{n-1}$ such stacks. (See [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=j3kZBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) beginning on page 25.)

---

## Question

How many such stacks are left-right symmetric? By my brute force program:

```
n  | # symmetric stacks
---+-------------------
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 3
4  | 3
5  | 7
6  | 9
7  | 19
8  | 25
9  | 53
10 | 71
11 | 149
12 | 203
13 | 423
14 | 583
15 | 1209
```

And by a parity argument, there are an odd number of such stacks for each value of $n$.

---

## Examples

For example, the following three stacks of four bricks are legal:
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

## Non-Examples

The following three stacks are not legal because they violate the three conditions above: in the first, the base is not contiguous; in the second, the levels are not offset; and in the third, the second brick in the second row doesn't have any bricks below it.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is extremely similar to a Project Euler Problem

Comment: [My other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2731692/121988) is loosely related.

Comment: @RushabhMehta, can you find which problem? Perhaps [Problem 215](https://projecteuler.net/problem=215)?

Comment: Oops, this is not nearly as similar as I remember it to be. My bad. [Here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=502) is the problem.

Comment: I've submitted this to the OEIS as A320314. Right now it's a draft, but I expect it will be added as a sequence within a few days.